# Nodejs json.Stringify functions not displaying records

Tags: node.js

Am working with nodejs chat and everything is working fine.
When I run `console.log(res1);`
Am getting console.log response as follows

```
{"name":"nancy", "message":"my chat message"}
```

Now I want to get value of **name and message parameter** but it shows undefined in the console as per code below

```
console.log(res1.message);
console.log(res1[0].message);
```

**here is the the code**

```
 socket.on('send message', function(data){
socket.emit('response message', data);


var res1 = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(res1);
console.log(res1.message);
console.log(res1[0].message);
    });
});
```

Comment: directlly use `data.message`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts its input to a string not to an object AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `JSON.stringify()` what it does is, it converts your object to a string. So no object manipulation is possible on a `JSON.stringify()`ied variable.

Here to see the object use,

```js
var data = {"name":"nancy", "message":"my chat message"};

var res1 = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log("res1: ", res1); // String
console.log("data: ", data); // Object

console.log("res1 message: ", res1.message); // Manipulation on string - Wrong
console.log("data message: ", data.message); // Manipulation on object - Correct
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get message from `stringify` object.

```
var x = JSON.parse(res1);
console.log(x.message);
```

Comment: Why should he parse it? He stringified the object in the previous line

Comment: @bambam i just replied on what wrong did he do. if applied stringify and wants value from object then need to parse it first. He can directly access value from data no issue i just tell the issue with stringify.